# What are the requirements for position of custom attributes in an Erlang module?

Tags: erlang, dialyzer

It seems:

- Dialyzer and erlc both error when there is a user-defined attribute in a source file before `-module`

Shell session demonstrating:

```
~ cat sample.erl
-my_attr(my_value).
-module(sample).
-compile([export_all, nowarn_export_all]).

main(_) ->
    ok.

~ erlc sample.erl
sample.erl:1:2: no module definition
%    1| -my_attr(my_value).
%     |  ^

~ dialyzer sample.erl
  Checking whether the PLT /Users/mheiber/Library/Caches/erlang/.dialyzer_plt is up-to-date... yes
  Proceeding with analysis...
dialyzer: Analysis failed with error:
Could not scan the following file(s):
/Users/mheiber/sample.erl:1:2: no module definition

Last messages in the log cache:
  Reading files and computing callgraph...
```

Is the contract for order of user-defined attributes documented anywhere? Or is this a bug?

All I could find in the docs is that predefined attributes must come before function declarations:

https://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/modules.html#pre-defined-module-attributes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> -module(Module).
>
> Module declaration, defining the name of the module. The name Module,
> an atom, is to be same as the file name minus the extension .erl.
> Otherwise code loading does not work as intended.
>
> **This attribute is to be specified first** and is the only mandatory attribute.